# vuejs v2 - Delete item from array after computed reverse

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a input that accepts barcode scanner input and puts all values in a data array. This is working perfect. I then want to display this data row by row but in the reverse order so the most recently scanned item is on top. I accomplish this by the following:

```
data: {
    barcodes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
},

methods: {
    deleteBarcode(index) {
        this.barcodes.splice(index, 1); 
    }
},    

computed: {
    reversedOrderBarcodes() {
        return this.barcodes.slice().reverse();
  }
},
```

In the view I do this:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="items" v-for="(barcode, index) in reversedOrderBarcodes">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:7px;">
            <barcode :value="barcode | capitalize" format="code128" height="25" margin="0" width="1" font-size="12" text-margin="0">
            </barcode>
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteBarcode(index)" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:10px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The barcodes display properly in the view. They are in the order `8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`. The problem is that in order for me to delete an item reactively it must be deleted from the `data` and not the computed array. The downside is the keys in the computed array do not match the original data array due to it being reversed so in this scenario clicking delete on the view row with `8` will delete the `data` array index `0` which has barcode `1`.

I have been searching for a way to delete by the barcode itself. Anyone know how I can display the computed array in reverse but still allow myself to delete it from the main reactive data array?

[image: reversed array]

Comment: Don't pass the index, pass the barcode itself, then find the index using the barcode and splice it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass barcode to delete function, then searching for matching barcode in `this.barcodes` array:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="items" v-for="(barcode, index) in reversedOrderBarcodes">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:7px;">
            <barcode :value="barcode | capitalize" format="code128" height="25" margin="0" width="1" font-size="12" text-margin="0">
            </barcode>
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteBarcode(barcode)" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:10px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
methods: {
    deleteBarcode(barCode) {
       const barCodeIndex = this.barcodes.findIndex(code => code === barCode)
       if (barCodeIndex >= 0) {
         this.barcodes.splice(barCodeIndex, 1)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not so vue or js task as math one:

```
deleteBarcode(index) {
    this.barcodes.splice(this.barcodes.length - 1 - index, 1);
}
```